# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at XYZ api(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-A

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors

I am getting  this error while calling api through React JS.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at *https://xyze.com/login/oauth2* (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

The functionality I want is, when I call a api through React JS it should get redirect to another api (redirection of the api has been taken care at the node js backend). While calling the redirected api I am facing CORS policy issue.

eg.
When I click on log in button below api gets called

```
axios.get('https://exampleabc.com/oauth')
```

and at the backend it recognises 'oauth' and redirect to 'https://xyze.com/login/oauth2'.

So here while redirecting to https://xyze.com/login/oauth2 it is giving CORS policy issue.

**Note:** I have added Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ in the api call and tried adding Proxy in package.json  but still facing the issue. Also cannot share the actual API due to security reasons

Answer (score -1):

This is mainly a backend server side issue that you are facing. Check in the Response headers of your pre-flight request what value you are getting in **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header and if it is matching with your request origin.
You can allow the origin in the preflight request headers to get through this error.
I got same error while using google OAuth2.0, but opening the login window from the react application worked for me.
you can directly redirect browser using

```
window.open("URL","_self","","")
```